# help in approaching this problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is a new scheme started by AirTel in Karnataka which allowed institutions to host websites on their servers by paying for only 4 of the 7 days per week. However, the service cannot be discontinued before 1 year from the date the agreement was signed and the four days will have to be selected in the beginning and cannot be changed during the year. Also on holidays, the server will have to be paid for due to excessive load. (Note: Sunday is not considered as a holiday unless it is explicitly mentioned)

Since the project receives limited funding, it needed to make sure that it uses the money as efficiently as possible. Your job is to decide the four days on which the service should be paid so as to save as much money as possible.

Input

The first line consists of an integer t (1<=t<=100), the number of test case. t test cases follow.
The first line of each test case is an integer n (1<=n<=365) denoting the number of holidays. n lines follow which will consist of three space separated integer d, m and y denoting the date of the holiday in dd mm yyyy format. The year may be normal or leap year. The holidays mentioned for one test case will always be of the same year. d and m can be single digit integers depending of the day and month, respectively. y is always a four digit number. d/m/y will always be a valid date.
Output

For each test case, print the four days in the order in which they appear in a week.
Note: Sunday is considered to be the first day of the week.
Example

Input:
1
4
3 5 2005
5 2 2005
20 8 2005
12 10 2005

Output:
Sunday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Saturday

Comment: This wouldn't be a problem from an ongoing contest, would it?

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of holidays which occur on each day of the week using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week) Wikipedia article on mapping dates to days of the week.

Note that a year has 52 weeks and 1 or 2 days (if it is a regular or [leap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) year). From this, and knowing the starting day of the contract (using the article above), you can calculate the number of each day there are until the end of the contract.

Given the number of each day of the week which occur, you can calculate the amount paid for choosing to pay on that day. Add in the extra costs due to each holiday, and you know the costs for each day should you choose to pay on that day. Then, pick the 4 days with the lowest cost (breaking ties arbitrarily).